# Get independent variable from SymPy Poly

Tags: sympy

I can create a sympy Poly object.

```py
from sympy.abc import x, mu
my_poly = poly(x ** 2 + x + mu, x)
print(my_poly)
```

Which prints

```bash
Poly(x**2 + x + mu, x, domain='ZZ[mu]')
```

How do I get my symbolic variable `x` from `my_poly`. In this case I know it is `x` but my other code needs to work for generic polynomials.

I can get it with `list(my_poly.free_symbols - my_poly.free_symbols_in_domain)[0]`, is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gens` property will give you a tuple of generators. If you always have only one then `p.gens[0]` is all you need to get `x`, the generator you specified at instantiation.